# induced homomorphism of adjoint action on fundamental group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a non-connected compact Lie group and $Ad_g: G \rightarrow G, x \rightarrow gxg^{-1}$ be the adjoint action. Look at the induced homomorphism $ (Ad_g)_*  : \pi_1 (G) \rightarrow \pi_1(G)$. If $g$ lies in the  indentity component of $G$ , then $ (Ad_g)_*$ is the identity map. What kind of special property does $ (Ad_g)_*$ have if $g$ is not in the identity component of $G$ besides it is an isomorphism? Is it an nilpotent group action or even also the identity map? I bet this is not true in general but do not know a counterexample.

Comment: Consider the semi-direct product $G$ of a product $H$ of circle groups with any finite subgroup of the automorphism group of $H$.

Comment: I see, in your mentioned example, take $g=(id, f), f \in Aut (H)$ such that $f_*: \pi_1(H) \rightarrow \pi_1(H)$ is not identity (or not a nilpotent group action), then $(Ad_g)_*: \pi_1(G) \rightarrow \pi_1(G) $ is also not identity (or not a nilpotent group action), right?